# How to check if the user pressed a key in Python without using getch()?

Tags: python, debugging, pyscripter

I would like to interrupt a loop if the user presses a particular key and continue executing after the loop. The following code should work when stdin is available.

```
While True:
    # Do stuff here.
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key = msvcrt.getch()
        if key == somekey:
            break
```

My problem is that stdin is not available in the PyScripter IDE debugger which I am using for development. Is there another way to do this that bypasses stdin? The solution can be Windows specific if necessary.

P.S. I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 with PyScripter using the 'Remote' Python Engine (whatever that means).

P.P.S. I rewrote this question based on feedback from dbliss below.

Comment: what do you mean by "in the Python debugger"?  are you using the `pdb` module in your code?

Comment: @dbliss I'm using PyScripter which does not seem to use the pdb module under the hood. The problem seems to be that the PyScripter debugger is intercepting stdin. I re-wrote the question to make it clearer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, the following code should do the trick:

```
import win32api
import win32con

print "Doing stuff; press F12 to interrupt."
While True:
    # Do stuff here.
    if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_F12) != 0:
        break
```